# How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

I have the following code but it is not working. I am fairly new to VBA as well. The code works to populate the email template but as soon as I add the .Attachment.Add it does not work.

```
Sub CreateMail()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("E2")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("E3")
    Set rngBody = .Range("E4")
    .Attachments.Add "Z:\PHS 340B\Letters of Non-Compliance\..Resources\W9 Form\VPNA W-9 01 09 2017"
End With

With objMail
    .to = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = rngSubject.Value
    .Body = rngBody.Value
    .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes I copied it straight from the shared network drive

Comment: The error says "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub emailtest()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
Set rngTo = .Range("E2")
Set rngSubject = .Range("E3")
Set rngBody = .Range("E4")
End With

With objMail
.To = rngTo.Value
.Subject = rngSubject.Value
.Body = rngBody.Value
.Attachments.Add "Z:\PHS 340B\Letters of Non-Compliance\..Resources\W9 Form\VPNA W-9 01 09 2017"
.Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
            or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

You need to use the .Attachments.Add when working within Outlook not Excel.

Comment: What does that mean? I am using Outlook to create the email which works fine its only when I try to add an attachment.

Comment: The attachment is a .pdf

Comment: @Twinkievizzio11 Try copying and pasting the code as I posted, it worked when I tested it. You had Attachments.Add within your "With Activesheet", you needed it under "With objMail".
.

Comment: thank you so much!! Works perfectly. You're the Best!

Comment: @Twinkievizzio11, please be sure to mark Ziggus's answer as the accepted one. Just click the checkmark below the down vote arrow on his post. Also, I wanted to add that the reason this works is because you mistakenly had the attachment being added under the wrong area of code. The object `ActiveSheet` doesn't support `.Attachments.Add`, so it needed to be moved to the `With objMail` area. Just a little clarification for anyone still confused. 

Answer (score 2):

This simple script should illustrate the point of how to add attachments to an email, and then send the email.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'This example send the last saved version of the Activeworkbook
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail1.htm