# AddAttachment in excel VBA not able to attach file in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written this very simple code to attach a file in my email, but the email comes without an attachment.

It doesn't even throw any error. I have made sure that the path is correct and the file exists.
Please help

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim Source_File As String

    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .To = "arushi.agarwal@in.ab-inbev.com"
        .Subject = "This is a test message k"
        .Body = "Please use this template for your weekly meeting today"
        .Send        ' SEND MESSAGE.
        .AddAttachment ("C:\Claims\Try.docx")
    End With

    ' CLEAR.
    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    '

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Arushi, you can try using .Attachments.Add("C:\Claims\Try.docx") instead of .AddAttachment ("C:\Claims\Try.docx")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775858/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-vba-in-excel)

Comment: You are sending the email before adding the attachment.

Comment: @Don't now Outlook, but maybe you should write **.Send** below the **.AddAttachment..,** line.

Comment: Classics: *"Push ›send‹ and then realize that you forgot to attach a file"* … the code way ;) To be consistent just send a second mail *"forgot to attach the file"*.

Comment: Actually this line `.AddAttachment ("C:\Claims\Try.docx")` **does throw an error** but you told VBA in case of error `GoTo ErrHandler` and your `ErrHandler:` does nothing, so you will never see a message if somethings goes wrong. That's why you didn't find your issue: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: OMG, so stupid of me. Thank you so much guys. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have made minor changes in your code and it works for me. You also need to attach the file before sending the email (e.g. .attachment before .send)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim Source_File As String

    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .To = "arushi.agarwal@in.ab-inbev.com"
        .Subject = "This is a test message k"
        .Body = "Please use this template for your weekly meeting today"
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Claims\Try.docx")
        .Send        ' SEND MESSAGE.
        '.AddAttachment ("C:\Claims\Try.docx")

    End With

    ' CLEAR.
    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Range("A1").Value = Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to have a `Exit Sub` right before `ErrHandler:` or it triggers the handler even if there is no error.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, it was very helpful :D