# Email Attachment with specific word

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I want to add attachment from specific folder (Path) I am looking for macro to pick up attachment name from column D but only last word as attachment in folder will contain only last word in given folder.

for eg. in D2 macro will search in specified folder for word "QR" and add the attachment.

```
Sub SendMultipleEmailsaa()

Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim arr() As Variant

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow),         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
.SetRange ws.UsedRange
.Header = False
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

arr = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

 Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

first = 2

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)


If i = UBound(arr) Then GoTo YO
If arr(i + 1, 1) = arr(i, 1) Then
            first = WorksheetFunction.Min(first, i + 1)
Else
YO:
Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

With OutApp
     .Subject = ws.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
     .Body = "Your message here"
     .Display
     .To = ws.Range("B" & i + 1).Value
     For j = first To i
        .Recipients.Add ws.Range("B" & j).Value
     Next
     first = i + 2

End With
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the Full Path of the File ? Or the Folder with Files

Comment: F:\WIN7PROFILE\Desktop\File

Comment: All of the files are present in this folder `File ?`

Comment: Yes, all files available in this folder

Comment: Can you also add the screenshot of the Folder ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775858/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-vba-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this part of your code:**

```
With OutApp
     .Subject = ws.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
     .Body = "Your message here"
     .Display
     .To = ws.Range("B" & i + 1).Value
     For j = first To i
        .Recipients.Add ws.Range("B" & j).Value
     Next
     first = i + 2

End With
```

**With:**

```
pth = "F:\WIN7PROFILE\Desktop\File\"
With OutApp
     .Subject = ws.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
     .Body = "Your message here"
     .Display
     .To = ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
     .Attachments.Add pth & Dir(pth & "*" & Replace(ws.Range("D" & i + 1).Value, "File - Fund ", "") & "*")
     For j = first To i
        .Recipients.Add ws.Range("A" & j).Value
     Next
     first = i + 2

End With
```

Comment: You may need a file extension on your attachment line as well

Comment: I am sorry but this code is not working as file names in the path are not the same, file name contain only last word for eg. for D2 "File - Fund QR" file name will be "Jan 2019 QR SMS"

Comment: @khyatidedhia I think you need to go back to the drawing board. Store the file name in your attachment column otherwise you're just turning this into a headache. To achieve what you want you'll need to manipulate the string for the last bit (easy enough) loop through all files in your directory to find possibly one that contains that string and then add. But what happens for multiple files?

Comment: @Tom I have added a DIR function now.

Comment: @Mikku Won't this fall over if the file isn't found?

Comment: @Tom ...True, it will fail if file is not found.

Comment: @khyatidedhia .. As Tom suggested, you should enter the file path in one column to be sure and run this code without any problems.

Comment: Yes, Its working but code is picking up same attachment multiple times

Comment: @khyatidedhia , I have tested it. You must be copying it in th wrong way

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your quick help.. you are awesome :)