# Outlook array index out of bounds when trying to display MailItem after MailItem.Attachments.Add has failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm calling Outlook from an Excel VBA macro to send an attachment via email. If for some reason an attachment cannot be added to the `MailItem`, I get the "Array index out of bounds" error when trying to display the `MailItem`.

When I checked value of `MailItem.Attachments.Count`, it showed `1`, even though attachment was not added to the email. I tried removing the attachment using `MailItem.Attachments.Remove 1`, but count of attachments still shows `1` and the "Array index out of bounds" error still appears when trying to display.

I've come across [this thread](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=14594), which is about developing Office Add-Ins in C#, and it suggests releasing all COM objects. I'm not sure how to do it and if it's even relevant. I tried setting all objects except the `MailItem` to `Nothing`, but that didn't help.

**UPD**: The question that was suggested in comments does not solve my problem. In that question the wrong object was used to access the `Attachments` property. Here I'm using `Outlook.MailItem.Attachments`, which I believe is correct.

Here's the sample code:

```
Public Sub ForStackOverflow()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Dim Attachments As Object
    Dim Attachment As Object
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With MailItem
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .Body = "test"
        Set Attachments = .Attachments

        On Error Resume Next

        Set Attachment = Attachments.Add("C:\Temp\ThisFileDoesNotExist.txt") 
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            .Send                       '<-- This works fine because attachment was added successfully
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Attachment.Delete          'This and any of the below didn't work
            'Set Attachment = Nothing
            'Attachments.Remove 1
            'Set Attachments = Nothing
            
            .Display                    '<-- Error 440: Array index out of bounds on this line
        End If
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775858/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-vba-in-excel)

Comment: @niton, in that question OP tried to use a `Worksheet` object to access property `Attachments`. Here I'm using property `Attachments` of an `Outlook.MailItem` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `On Error Resume Next` you found there is something indicating there is an attachment, you cannot remove, that triggers an "Array index out of bounds" error.

Test for the file instead of applying the code of last resort, `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub ForStackOverflow_FileExistsTest()

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Dim pathFile As String
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With MailItem
    
        pathFile = "C:\Temp\ThisFileDoesNotExist.txt"
        
        If Len(dir(pathFile)) > 0 Then
        
            .Attachments.Add (pathFile)
            .Display
            
        Else
        
            MsgBox pathFile & " does not exist."
            .Display
            
        End If
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I'll do that. I was more wondering if there's a way to fix the `MailItem` object once an attachment has already been "added", but I agree that it's better to prevent this. Thanks for you time and your answer.