# Browse folders to attach files in Outlook mail using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am working on an userform in VBA Excel that allows a user to submit their request. The users complete the form then click on the Send button. An Outlook mail will be opened and the completed form is automatically attached.

The users usually have data or/and documents related to the request. I want to add functionality to my userform, which allows them to browse their PC and import the files. When they click on the Send button, these files will be attached to the same mail as the original Excel form.

Below are the codes for my Send button.

```vb
Function CreationMail(criticité As String)
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xFormat As Long
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulaire")
    Set rng = Sheets("Formulaire").Range("C6:D11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Select Case Wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
    xFile = ".xlsx"
    xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
    If Wb2.HasVBProject Then
        xFile = ".xlsm"
        xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Else
        xFile = ".xlsx"
        xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End If
    Case Excel8:
        xFile = ".xls"
        xFormat = Excel8
    Case xlExcel12:
        xFile = ".xlsb"
        xFormat = xlExcel12
    End Select
    FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    FileName = "STATSAE" & "_" & Format(Now, "yymmdd") & "_" & Format(Now, "hhnnss")

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Wb2.SaveAs FilePath & FileName & xFile, FileFormat:=xFormat
            
    With OutlookMail
        .To = ";" & ";"
        .CC = ""
        If criticité = "Haute" Then
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        End If
        If criticité = "" Then
            .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        End If
        If criticité = "Faible" Then
            .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        End If
        .Subject = "Request" & Space(1) & FileName
        .Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
        .Body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
            
    Wb2.Close
    Kill FilePath & FileName & xFile
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776096/8422953)

Comment: You'll probably want to use `Application.filedialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` to get the full file name, see [here](https://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to do customizations to your form to pick up files that requires to be attached to the email. Then in the code you can repeat the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method of the `Attachments` class for each entry the user has chosen. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

```
.Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
.Attachments.Add your_chosen_file
```