# How to add an attachment to an email and send to multiple adresses from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found the following script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775858/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-vba-in-excel/48776096#48776096?newreg=c70a6b475f9f4a42ade49de17aa995f3):

```
    Sub emailtest()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
Set rngTo = .Range("E2")
Set rngSubject = .Range("E3")
Set rngBody = .Range("E4")
End With

With objMail
.To = rngTo.Value
.Subject = rngSubject.Value
.Body = rngBody.Value
.Attachments.Add "Z:\PHS 340B\Letters of Non-Compliance\..Resources\W9 Form\VPNA W-9 01 09 2017"
.Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
            or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing

End Sub
```

I changed *Set rngTo = .Range("E2")* to *Set rngTo = .Range("G8:G38")* , running the script it gives a 440 Error on :*.to = rngTo.Value*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a multi-cell range, `rngTo.Value` will return a 2-D array, not a string.  You need to loop over the range and build a string with e-mail addresses separated by `;`

Answer (score 2):

What Tim said above. Try this.

```
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim emails as string
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
Set rngTo = .Range("G8:G38")
Set rngSubject = .Range("E3")
Set rngBody = .Range("E4")
End With

For Each E In rngTo
    emails = emails & E & ";"
Next

With objMail
.To = emails
.Subject = rngSubject.Value
.Body = rngBody.Value
'.Attachments.Add "Z:\PHS 340B\Letters of Non-Compliance\..Resources\W9 Form\VPNA W-9 01 09 2017"
.Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
            or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
```