# Add multiple attachments to an e-mail from excel table - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, attachment

I have a VBA macro to send e-mails to different recipients, but now I want to add attachments. The problem is the attachments paths are in an excel table and it varies according to the customer. I.e. customer A has 3 lines in the table, each with a different attachment, cust B has 5 lines, and so on.
Anyone knows how to vlookup it and get all possible files paths? Here follows my current code without attachments:

```
Sub Controle_de_orçamentos()

response = MsgBox("Deseja enviar as cobranças?", vbYesNo)
 
If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("Então tchau")
    Exit Sub
End If


    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim mailAddress As String

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    
    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = ActiveSheet

    'Set filter range and filter column (Column with names)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:H" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 1    'Filter column = A because the filter range start in A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
            CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))
    
                                              
    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'Look for the mail address in the MailInfo worksheet
            mailAddress = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                          VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
                                Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:B" & _
                                Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 2, False)
                        On Error GoTo 0

            If mailAddress <> "" Then
                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                
                End With
                
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

   
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = mailAddress
                    .Subject = "Orçamentos aguardando aprovação - Indi Empilhadeiras"
                    .HTMLBody = "Prezados(as), boa tarde!<br>" & _
                    "Poderiam, por gentileza, informar se os orçamentos abaixo estão aprovados?" & RangetoHTML(rng) & _
                    "<br>Obrigado!<br>" & _
                    "Denis Scalco<br>" & _
                    "(15) 98145-0856"
                    .Display  'Or use Send
                    .Send
                  
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0

                Set OutMail = Nothing
            End If

            'Close AutoFilter
            Ash.AutoFilterMode = False
            
        Next Rnum
        
    End If

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Cws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could come up with a loop that reads the *next* line and moves to next customer only if the name/ID changes - or, far simpler - maybe use `COUNTIF` to find out how many lines the customer has?

Answer (score 0):

To filter the files for a specific customer you may want to use standard or advanced filtering:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b

read file names of attachments from range: see below code proposal

add attachments
[How to add an attachment to an email using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775858/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-an-email-using-vba-in-excel)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim myA(20) As String
Dim myCt As Integer
Dim NrFiles As Integer
    
    Call ReadAttachments(myA, Range("H1:H10"), False, NrFiles)
    For myCt = 1 To NrFiles
        Debug.Print myCt, myA(myCt)
    Next myCt
    
End Sub

Sub ReadAttachments(ByRef myAttachments() As String, myRange As Range, _
hasHeader As Boolean, FileCt As Integer)

Dim myCell As Range
Dim iCt As Integer

    For Each myCell In myRange
        If iCt <> 0 Then
            If myCell.Value <> "" Then
                myAttachments(iCt) = myCell.Value
                FileCt = FileCt + 1
            End If
        End If
        iCt = iCt + 1
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! The code for adding the attachments only supports when you have a single file always. And one question: the code you suggested should be placed before mine? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner and this whole macro is a Frankenstein xP